# Is it a good practice to create a sidebar using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

A couple of months ago I realized I needed to update a sidebar annually with a new link. Now instead of going through each page and inserting the link (about 20 pages), I decided to create a javascript file and link it to each page. The script would create links and append them to the page. This meant that each time we needed to create a new link, we'd only need to add a new line to the javascript file once and the change would be reflected on each page. Essentially cutting down on time wasted going through all pages and adding the new link. I wonder if this is a good practice and could there be problems I failed to foresee?

The code is listed below:

```
function createVolume (text, link){
  var volDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var textDiv = document.createTextNode(text);
  var linkDiv = document.createElement("a");
  linkDiv.setAttribute("href", link);
  volDiv.setAttribute("class", "volume");
  volDiv.appendChild(textDiv);
  linkDiv.appendChild(volDiv);
  var d = document.getElementById("e27");
  d.appendChild(linkDiv);
}
var bhbHome = createVolume("BHB Home", "bhb.html");
var v76 = createVolume("Volume 76", "bhb76.html");
var v75 = createVolume("Volume 75", "bhb75.html");
var v74 = createVolume("Volume 74", "bhb74.html");
var v73 = createVolume("Volume 73", "bhb73.html");
var v72 = createVolume("Volume 72", "bhb72.html");
var v71 = createVolume("Volume 71", "bhb71.html");
var v70 = createVolume("Volume 70", "bhb70.html");
var v69 = createVolume("Volume 69", "bhb69.html");
var v68 = createVolume("Volume 68", "bhb68.html");
var v67 = createVolume("Volume 67", "bhb67.html");
var v6566 = createVolume("Volume 65 and 66", "bhb_65_66.html");
var v64 = createVolume("Volume 64", "bhb64.html");
var v63 = createVolume("Volume 63", "bhb63.html");
var v626160 = createVolume("Volume 60, 61, and 62", "bhb_60_61_62.html");
var v59 = createVolume("Volume 59","bhb59.html");
```

Comment: This is pretty hacky. How about using a real templating solution?

Comment: I would prefer server side link generation, so links will be indexed by search engines.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento, If it not needs to be then it's different but still now its a bad practice.

Comment: @MattBall I could but it's a bunch of static pages without a server-side. Frankly I only did it because the whole site was a mess and I was looking for hacky ways to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some drawbacks i can think of, the first two assuming the code is run when the DOM is ready:

1. there can be a re-arrange effect, with the user first seeing the page
   without the sidebar and then with it
2. you need to make sure that
   other code running on the page that requires the sidebar is run only
   after the sidebar has been created.
3. (@Sheikh Heera) some search engines will not be able to index your entire page

The traditional way of doing things is by using server side includes, so look into that if you can.

Comment: I run it at the bottom of the page. If that helps with DOM being ready.

Answer (score 1):

It's not good practice. You should do it with server side code, such as a server side include, php etc. Doing it this way will not work for people without Javscript, and good practice is to do it server side.

Comment: Not necessarily true. Google can see at least some js: http://moz.com/ugc/can-google-really-access-content-in-javascript-really

Comment: @yochannah Thanks, wasn't aware of it, will have a good read of that later. Answer updated.

Comment: That's what I was worried about. People without JS will struggle. But then again, they probably struggle with their whole internet experience

Answer (score 1):

No, the most straightforward solution is to use a server-side script.

If your pages are mainly static, and update rarely, yea suppose it could work. But really, just use wordpress or something.

Comment: Yeah, it's a terrible site in terms of server side. It's just a bunch of static pages and whatnot. It was built using Yahoo! sitebuilder and if you've worked with it you'll understand what a load of bollocks it is (I only started working with the site a few months back and it does my head in!).

Comment: You can probably get this working with server side includes, which is unobtrusive. Just add an include directive to each page, to include a file with the sidebar in it, and then you can just continue only updating one place. No other changes to your current pages necessary. Setting them up may be a little fiddly, but just a couple of things to think about, not much.

Answer (score 1):

**It's not good practice!!!!!!!!.**

*Use references to cite why its not a good practice and the possible problems*

**Don't assume the user has a dynamic HTTP content capable server**

**Don't assume the user wants search engines getting their links**

Answer (score 0):

For maintenance purposes it's definitely a good idea to create re-used elements only once. I would, however, always prefer to do this on the server-side for the following reasons:

1. Including the script client-side will result in unneccessary http requests.
2. The browser needs to be Javascript-enabled.
3. This causes unneccessary DOM manipulations. I'm far away from being an expert, but I'm sure this will cost some time.

This list is most definitely incomplete, but these are the topics that would bother me the most. If for some reason you don't have the chance or the knowledge to use a server side programming language you might want to dig into [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes). This provides a very easy-to-use technique for what you want to achieve and it should be available on common web servers.